# R Megre Data Frame Column and Recode

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 R data frames that looks like this:

**DATA FRAME 1:**

| identifier | ef_posterior | position_no | classification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 0.260 | 1 | yes |
| 11111 | 0.0822 | 2 | yes |
| 11111 | 0.00797 | 3 | yes |
| 11111 | 0.04 | 4 | no |
| 11111 | 0.245 | 5 | yes |
| 11111 | 0.432 | 6 | yes |
| 11112 | 0.342 | 1 | maybe |
| 11112 | 0.453 | 2 | yes |
| 11112 | 0.0032 | 3 | yes |
| 11112 | 0.241 | 5 | no |
| 11112 | 0.0422 | 6 | yes |
| 11112 | 0.311 | 4 | no |

**DATAFRAME 2:**

| study_identifier | %LVEF |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 62 |
| 11112 | 76 |

I want to merge and rearrange these two data frames into something like this:

Study_identifier and identifier are the same thing (just different column names). Additionally, I would like to recode the classification so that yes = 0, no = 1, maybe = 2

| identifier | pos_1 | pos_1_class | pos_2 | pos_2_class | pos_3 | pos_3_class | pos_4 | pos_4_class | pos_5 | pos_5_class | pos_6 | pos_6_class | %LVEF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 0.260 | 0 | 0.0822 | 0 | 0.00797 | 0 | 0.04 | 1 | 0.245 | 0 | 0.432 | 0 | 62 |
| 11112 | 0.342 | 2 | 0.453 | 0 | 0.0032 | 0 | 0.311 | 1 | 0.241 | 1 | 0.0422 | 0 | 76 |

```
df1 %>% mutate(position_no = paste0("position_", position_no)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = identifier, names_from = position_no, values_from = ef_posterior) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(study_identifier = as.numeric(as.character(study_identifier))), by = c("identifier" = "study_identifier"))
```

This is the code I have right now, but I can't figure out where to put in the code for the classification column

How would I go about doing this?
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recode quite easily with `dplyr` and `case_when`:

```
df1 %>% mutate(
  classification = 
    case_when( classification == "yes" ~ 1,
               classification == "no" ~ 0,
               classification == "maybe" ~ 2)
)
```

I would solve it the following way:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  identifier = c(11111L,11111L,11111L,11111L,
                 11111L,11111L,11112L,11112L,11112L,11112L,11112L,
                 11112L),
  ef_posterior = c(0.26,0.0822,0.00797,0.04,
                   0.245,0.432,0.342,0.453,0.0032,0.241,0.0422,0.311),
  position_no = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L),
  classification = c("yes","yes","yes","no",
                     "yes","yes","maybe","yes","yes","no","yes","no")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
  study_identifier = c(11111L, 11112L),
  `%LVEF` = c(62L, 76L)
)

df1 %>% mutate(
  classification = 
    case_when( classification == "yes" ~ 1,
               classification == "no" ~ 0,
               classification == "maybe" ~ 2)
) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(identifier), names_from = c(position_no), values_from = c(classification,ef_posterior)) %>% 
left_join(df2, by = c("identifier" = "study_identifier"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 14
#>   identifier classification_1 classification_2 classification_3 classification_4
#>        <int>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1      11111                1                1                1                0
#> 2      11112                2                1                1                0
#> # … with 9 more variables: classification_5 <dbl>, classification_6 <dbl>,
#> #   ef_posterior_1 <dbl>, ef_posterior_2 <dbl>, ef_posterior_3 <dbl>,
#> #   ef_posterior_4 <dbl>, ef_posterior_5 <dbl>, ef_posterior_6 <dbl>,
#> #   `%LVEF` <int>
```

Created on 2021-04-12 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)